# how to keep value result query but outside looping foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

### this is my code

```
global $wpdb;

foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM detail_buyer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") as $key => $row)
{    
       $barang=$row->nama_barang;
       //in this table field 'nama_barang' have values more than one
}

echo $barang;
```

---

but output result look like this

---

**tempe**

---

any idea how I could do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this :

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM detail_buyer ORDER BY id DESC");
$barang = array();
foreach( $results as $key => $row)
{    
       $barang[] = $row->nama_barang;
       //in this table field 'nama_barang' have values more than one
}

echo implode(', ', $barang);
```

I've deleted the `LIMIT 1` witch was limiting your request to 1 result.

PS : Never put your query directly in your loop instruction.

Edit : For more explanation, I replace your variable by an array, I keep each value in it, and at the end I show our array as a string (using ', ' as separator).

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer !

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't unserstand,what do you mean 'validate'? for example?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `LIMIT` in your query,

```
SELECT * FROM detail_buyer ORDER BY id DESC
```

For keep your results of values, you need to create an `array` variable and store into them. 
like this

```
$barang[] =$row->nama_barang;
```

Try this,

```
global $wpdb;

foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM detail_buyer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") 
         as $key => $row)
{
       $barang[] =$row->nama_barang; // changes made here
       //in this table field 'nama_barang' have values more than one
}

print_r($barang);
```